# tempate argument deducing in returned templated class

Tags: c++

I'd like to implement a following class:

```
class A
{
public:
    template<typename VAL_TYPE>
    class PP {
    public:
        PP();
        void init(const string &name);

        operator VAL_TYPE();
        VAL_TYPE & operator = (const VAL_TYPE&);

    private:
        string _name;
        VAL_TYPE _val;

        void getter();
        void setter();

    };

    A();
public:    
    template<typename VAL_TYPE>
    PP<VAL_TYPE>& operator[](const string& name);

private:
    PP<int> _pp_int;
    PP<double> _pp_float;
    PP<string> _pp_string;
};
```

`getter` and `setter` methods are implemented in .cpp file for the 'int', 'double' and 'string' types separately:

```
void A::PP<int>::setter()
{
   ...
}
void A::PP<int>::getter()
{
   ...
}
```

and so on for the 'double' and 'string' types.

The question is about the overloaded A::operator[].
It should return `P<int>` (_pp_int member) or `PP<double>` (_pp_float member) or `PP<string>` (_pp_string member) according to
value of 'name' parameter. The aim is use of something like this:

```
A a;

a["iii"] = 10;
int i = a["iii"];

a["ddd"] = 3.141519;
double d = a["ddd"];

a["sss"] = "string";
string s = a["sss"];
```

As I understand here is a big problem: how compiler deduce the template argument `VAL_TYPE` in A::operator[].

Is it possible to implement such idea?
I read many posts but still can not find any solution.

May be it is possible in the frame of Qt library?

Comment: Basically compiler can't deduce function result type only parameter types...

Comment: Perhaps you might want to take a look at `boost::any`. What you're building is very much like a `std::map< std::string, boost::any >`.

Comment: I design the `class A` as a wrapper on some external SDK. The `A::operator[]` is a interface to SDK "features" (in notaion of the SDK) and `class A::PP` is a proxy type to access it. The "features" have different `get/set` functions and I want to incapsulate it in the single class by the same access method. The `class A` has also many other methods to interact with the SDK, I prefer to not use of `boost`. Now I look towards `auto - decltype` construction but still have no ideas. (sorry for my English)

Comment: If you have a fixed set of keys, you could declare each key as an instance of e.g. `mykey<int>` or `mykey<double>` and then use template parameter deduction to call `details::fetch_proxy<T>` and return `T` when passed a `mykey<T>`.  If that sounds applicable to your case, let me know and I could expand this into a full answer.

Comment: Such a variant I already realized ealry. Not exactly as you suggest but very close. The main problem is that the set of keys is not fixed and may changed from version to version of the external SDK (some are deprecated, some are new).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can easily come is this:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using Map = std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::variant<std::string, int, double> >;

int main()
{
  Map m;
  m["iii"] = 5;
  int i = boost::get<int>(m["iii"]);
  m["ddd"] = 0.3;
  double d = boost::get<double>(m["ddd"]);
  m["sss"] = "hello";
  std::string s = boost::get<std::string>(m["sss"]);
  return 0;
}
```

This code works and does what you want. A boost variant is a "sum" type, it contains exactly one object, that has the type of one of the things it templated. So in other words, here they contain either strings, ints, or doubles.

When a boost variant is being assigned to, it will do type inference based on the assigned type and do the right thing. But there's no way for it to easily offer implicit conversions to all of the types. So you have to explicitly extract the value. Frankly I would recommend just using this as is and living with it, but I'm sure you didn't come hear to read that, so...

In your particular case, if you are willing to give up genericity, you can do this. Basically, you would just write a class that contains a boost variant, but you would also add implicit conversions for it.

```
class PP {
public:
  // forward heterogeneous assignment etc so that works as before

  operator std::string() { return boost::get<string>(m_data); }
  // similar for other types
private:
  boost::variant<std::string, int, double> m_data;
}
```

Now, when you try to assign a `PP` to a string, there will be no direct assignment, but the compiler will see that `PP` offers an implicit conversion to a string and use that.

The thing is, that this is opening a very big can of worms in terms of language complexity and is not worth it. Should it actually be offering conversion by value, by reference, what about constness, rvalues, etc etc. Also worth considering that `boost::get` will very loudly (by throwing) fail if the variant does not contain the requested type, so you now have a situation where innocent looking assignment operations can easily throw. I recommend learning about boost variant (which will probably become part of the standard soon, it's been discussed heavily) and learning about some of the techniques used there, like visitors. They may be alien at first but they work quite well, and they play to C++'s strengths, instead of trying to make C++ behave like python.

Comment: Thanks! I barked up the wrong tree! You suggest an idea how to use of the QVariant class in the Qt framework. As I see QVariant is very close by behavior to `boost::variant`. The matter in that I develop `class A` as just Qt wrapper to the external SDK.

Comment: @Timur Glad you found the answer helpful. If you feel like it answers your question, it would be common to upvote it and mark it as accepted :-)